# Decomposing equality of constructors coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Often in Coq I find myself doing the following: I have the proof goal, for example:

```
some_constructor a c d = some_constructor b c d
```

And I really only need to prove `a = b` because everything else is identical anyway, so I do:

```
assert (a = b).
```

Then prove that subgoal, then

```
rewrite H.
reflexivity.
```

finishes the proof.

But it seems to just be unnecessary clutter to have those hanging around at the bottom of my proof.

Is there a general strategy in Coq for taking an equality of constructors and splitting it up into an equality of constructor parameters, kinda like a `split` but for equalities rather than conjunctions.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50117934/1544337

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In particular, standard Coq provides the `f_equal` tactic.

```
Inductive u : Type := U : nat -> nat -> nat -> u.

Lemma U1 x y z1 z2 : U x y z1 = U x y z2.
f_equal
```

Also, ssreflect provides a general-purpose congruence tactic `congr`.

Comment: It seems to me that the tactic `f_equal` often produces more complicated terms than just `apply f_equal`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Coq's searching capabilities:

```
  Search (?X _ = ?X _).
  Search (_ _ = _ _).
```

Among some noise it reveals a lemma

```
f_equal: forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (x y : A), x = y -> f x = f y
```

And its siblings for multi-argument equalities: `f_equal2` ... `f_equal5` (as of Coq version 8.4).

Here is an example:

```
Inductive silly : Set :=
  | some_constructor : nat -> nat -> nat -> silly
  | another_constructor : nat -> nat -> silly.

Goal forall x y,
    x = 42 ->
    y = 6 * 7 ->
    some_constructor x 0 1 = some_constructor y 0 1.
  intros x y Hx Hy.
  apply f_equal3; try reflexivity.
```

At this point all you need to prove is `x = y`.

Comment: Yes, constructors are injective functions, that's why this approach will always work. And `f_equal` can be applied to every injective function. There is also a tactic `injection` which works on *hypotheses*. There is more information [here](http://adam.chlipala.net/itp/tactic-reference.html).

Comment: I do not understand why it is important that constructors are injective functions for `f_equal` to work. Note also that you are not forced to use `f_equal3` here, and that `apply (f_equal (fun k => some_constructor k 0 1)).` works.

Comment: @eponier Of course, `f_equal` may be applied to any equality of relevant form. But if a function is injective, it guarantees you don't throw away information (which you'd be useful later). For example, `Goal Z.abs 1 = Z.abs (-1). apply f_equal.` "works", but leaves you with `1 = -1` as the goal, because `Z.abs` is obviously not injective.

Comment: I'm with eponier here, injective means `f x = f y -> x = y`, whereas the original question is `x = y -> f x = f y`.

Comment: @ejgallego Yes, that's exactly right. If `f` (it's `some_constructor` in the OP) is injective, one can *always* apply `f_equal` to prove the goal, because of the injectivity condition you've mentioned above. That is not the case in general for an arbitrary function (as I've shown in my prev. comment). Upshot: I was talking about a sufficient condition, not a necessary one.

Comment: @AntonTrunov, umm, I'm not sure this is true. For instance, to prove `S 3 = S 4` from the proper hypothesis, applying `f_equal` is an unnecessary step.

Comment: @ejgallego Good point, but I didn't say that we always *have* to do it ;)